# Python code (with lambda) is very slow. How to speed it up?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, optimization

This python script processes 70 lines in about 30 seconds. The total amount of lines is 70k, which means that as it is the script is not useful.

How can I make it faster?

I have already tried Numba and multiprocessing, the former doesn't work the latter isn't faster.

```
import cpi
import datetime as df
from datetime import date, datetime
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
import pandas as pd 

transaction_df = pd.read_csv("tickets.csv")
transaction_df = transaction_df[['customer_country_code', 'processed_at', 'amount']]
transaction_df = transaction_df[-70:]

transaction_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(transaction_df['processed_at']).apply(lambda x: x.date())

dateTimeObj1 = datetime.now()
converter = CurrencyRates()


transaction_de = transaction_df[(transaction_df['customer_country_code'] == 'DE')]
transaction_de['amount'] = transaction_de.apply(lambda transaction_de: converter.convert( 'EUR', 'USD', transaction_de['amount'], transaction_de['date']), axis = 1)

transaction_gb = transaction_df[(transaction_df['customer_country_code'] == 'GB')]
transaction_gb['amount'] = transaction_gb.apply(lambda transaction_gb: converter.convert( 'GBP', 'USD', transaction_gb['amount'], transaction_gb['date']), axis = 1)

transaction_us = transaction_df[(transaction_df['customer_country_code'] == 'US')]

vertical_stack = pd.concat([transaction_us, transaction_de, transaction_gb], axis=0)
vertical_stack["Real_USD"] = vertical_stack.apply(lambda vertical_stack: cpi.inflate(vertical_stack["amount"], vertical_stack["date"]), axis=1)


dateTimeObj2 = datetime.now()

timeneeded = dateTimeObj2 - dateTimeObj1

print(timeneeded)
print(vertical_stack)
```

[Here the CProfiler first 50 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0x8M.png)

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Did you try to profile the code? What appears to be the bottleneck? What are all the tools used here, e.g. the `CurrencyRates` class and `cpi.inflate`? Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and try to create a [mre]/

Comment: CurrencyRates and cpi.inflate are needed to convert different currencies and to calculate inflation adjustment. 

Yes, I have run the Cprofile but I do not know how to read its outcome properly.

Comment: CPI Adjustment - https://towardsdatascience.com/the-easiest-way-to-adjust-your-data-for-inflation-in-python-365490c03969

Currency Rates - https://forex-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show relevant `import`s from third party libraries, etc. "Yes, I have run the Cprofile but I do not know how to read its outcome properly." Okay, so, why not *show it to us*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - thanks for the suggestions. I've added what you asked.

Comment: "This python script processes 70 lines in about 30 seconds." According to the profiler output that you show, it took 25 seconds, and almost 23 seconds of that was *downloading data*. You may want to try reading the documentation for those third party tools, to see if there is any way to make them use cached exchange-rate and CPI data.

Comment: (But [Please do not upload images of terminal output when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) It's easier for us to talk about the profiler output in answers, when we can copy and paste from it.)

Comment: If your data has lots of duplicate dates you might be better off making a df of conversion rates for those dates, merging the dfs on the date and doing the calculations yourself